# Enable/Disable Mobile Data (GPRS) using code on Froyo 2.2

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, 3g-network

I'm trying to Enable / Disable Mobile Data Connexion.
I've used this code by **rIHaN JiTHiN** ([Enable/Disable Mobile Data (GPRS) using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523396/enable-disable-mobile-data-gprs-using-code)) and it's works perfectly on Android 4.0, but it's doesn't on my Galaxy S (Froyo 2.2)...

Is there a way to enable / disable data connexion programmatically ?

If anyone had any idea why it's doesn't work on Froyo, would be really helpful. According to **rIHaN JiTHiN**, this code works on all Android version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether it is enabled or disabled by using below code

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mMobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

if (mMobile.isConnected()) {
    //if internet connected
}
```

if it is disabled, you can enable it on your `froyo` device by using this one

```
void turnData(boolean ON) throws Exception
{

if(bv == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
{

    Log.i("version:", "Found Froyo");
    try{ 
        Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
        Class telephonyManagerClass;
        Object ITelephonyStub;
        Class ITelephonyClass;
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
    Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
    getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
    ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
    ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

    if (ON) {
         dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity"); 

    } else {
        dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
    }
    dataConnSwitchmethod.setAccessible(true);
    dataConnSwitchmethod.invoke(ITelephonyStub);
    }catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("Error:",e.toString());
    }

}
 else
{
   Log.i("version:", "Found Gingerbread+");
   final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
   final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
   iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
   final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
   final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
   final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
   setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
   setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
}
```

and also dont forget to add these to `manifest`

```
android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer ! It's work perfectly. Actually, I've got a problem with the Manifest permission (android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS & android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE). I've fix up this like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801984/permission-is-only-granted-to-system-app.