# How to turn on off mobile internet xamarin.android programmatically Using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Please Guid me How to turn on/off mobile internet in xamarin.android programmatically Using c# in Visual studio 2013

and Please Guid ME what is this Below

```
[Android.Runtime.Register("CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE")] public const String ConnectivityService
```

in xamarin and how to use this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable/Disable Mobile Data (GPRS) using code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523396/enable-disable-mobile-data-gprs-using-code)

Comment: i already check that this is not duplicate can you answer that.
how to use [Android.Runtime.Register("CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE")] public const String ConnectivityService

Comment: @Sid , Question about on/off internet on xamarin.android not native android