# How to disable and enable mobile data Pro grammatically

Tags: java, android

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
    state = false;
    tBMobileData.setImageResource(R.drawable.dataoff);
} else {
    state = true;
    tBMobileData.setImageResource(R.drawable.dataon);
}
```

I want mobile data and wifi network disabled, and enabled from program. Is it possible or not?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically\

Comment: Check the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523396/enable-disable-mobile-data-gprs-using-code

Comment: -sasikumar  its code work only Rooted device but i want to android device

Comment: i have not got answer yet please help me